# Why i'm getting exception Parameter is not valid when trying to init a jpg image?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void Init()
{
  Bitmap ConvertedBmp;
  ConvertedBmp = new Bitmap(@"c:\temp\parrots.jpg");
}
```

The exception is on the line:

```
ConvertedBmp = new Bitmap(@"c:\temp\parrots.jpg");
```

I can edit and see the image on the hard disk.
The image size 29.3 KB
Also the image is 24 Bit depth

The exception:

```
System.ArgumentException occurred
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Parameter is not valid.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(String filename)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Is that the actual path you're using, or does your path have a typo or does it otherwise point to an inaccessible file? Does it work with a different file? Is the file readable by the user running the application? Please read [ask] and share your research.

Comment: Yes it's the right path and other images are working. The parrots.jpg i can edit it no problems with Paint. So the file is ok.

Comment: The exception posted seems to be incomplete. It's missing inner exception details. Please post it fully which may help to answer.